# Javascript Code isn't submitting to Parse

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I am creating an app to send an object to a class in Parse, but the data in the form is being passed and nothing happens. I can submit data directly from the function showAlert, but no alert appears after setNotification and and showALert is used. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>My Parse App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="My Parse App">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.18.min.js"></script>
</head>



<body>

  <div id="main">
    <h1>You're ready to use Parse!</h1>

    <p>Read the documentation and start building your JavaScript app:</p>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide">Parse JavaScript Guide</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.parse.com/docs/js">Parse JavaScript API Documentation</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div style="display:none" class="error">
      Looks like there was a problem saving the test object. Make sure you've set your application ID and javascript key correctly in the call to <code>Parse.initialize</code> in this file.
    </div>

    <div style="display:none" class="success">
      <p>You're message has now been submited.'</p>

    </div>
  </div>


<div class="login">
    <form class="login-form" name="login-form">
        <h2>Compose Message</h2>
        <input type="text" name="school" id="school" placeholder="School Code" />
        <p> </p>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
        <p> </p>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Message" />
        <p> </p>
<input type="button" value="Set Notification" onClick="setMessage();">
       <p> </p>
<input type="button" value="Send Notification" onClick="showAlert();">
    </form>
</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

      function setMessage (){

      var textField = form.school.value


      var textField1 = form.name.value


      var textField2 = form.password.value
      }

function showAlert() {
    Parse.initialize("appkey", "javascript key");



    var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend(textField);
    var testObject = new TestObject();
    testObject.save({teacher: textField1), message:textField2)}, {
      success: function(object) {
        $(".success").show();
                    alert('The Message has been sent!');
      },
      error: function(model, error) {
        $(".error").show();
                    alert('There has been an error.');
      }
    });
}
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am dusting off my Javascript knowledge to create an page that syncs to an iOS app. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've a similar issue, but my approach is slightly different. Have a look at my question in case any of the code helps you unlock your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064975/javascript-jquerry-code-block-is-not-updating-parse-com-class-object-correctly

Comment: I solved my problem by using prompts instead of text fields.